# How to Create "Instant Messaging" in Notepad++ - VBScript

Tags: loops, vbscript, notepad++, instant-messaging

As a past time with a couple of friends, I'm trying to make a sort of "instant messaging" through notepad++.

The setup is as follows:
Three computers are connected on a network. On computer 2, there is Notepad++ in its directory. On computer 3, there is the VBScript and the text file (which is opened in Notepad++). 
The "F5" key in Notepad++ has been rebound to "Reload From Disk" respectively.

The goal is to have Notepad++ refresh every 2 seconds or so, but exclusively in Notepad++, even in the background.  The VBScript is meant to close upon Notepad++ closing.

The VBScript is as follows (keep in mind I have no prior experience with VBScripts; expect major flaws):

```
strFileName = "\\08-111096-CISCO\Users\Straka.J\Downloads\Notepad++"  
Dim oShell

set oShell = CreateObject("wScript.Shell")  
oShell.Run "notepad++ ""\\08-111099-CISCO\Users\Javorsky.G\Downloads\New Text Document.txt"""  
oShell.AppActivate "\\08-111096-CISCO\Users\Straka.J\Downloads\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"  
Do    
    WScript.Sleep 500  
    oShell.SendKeys "{F5}"  
    wScript.Sleep 2000  
Loop Until Quit
```

Notepad++ will open the text file and will begin the F5 loop. However, the F5 will continue regardless if Notepad++ is the active window or not, and the script does not close upon Notepad++ closing.

I'm certainly missing something, but after several hours of research and experimenting, I couldn't find a solution.

Is it possible to achieve these results with just a VBScript?

Answer (score 0):

`AppActivate()` returns `True` if the call was successful (if it found and activated the window). Use that return value to determine whether to continue refreshing or to close your script.

```
Do While oShell.AppActivate("\\08-111096-CISCO\Users\Straka.J\Downloads\Notepad++\notepad++.exe")

    oShell.SendKeys "{F5}"
    WScript.Sleep 2000

Loop

' Script exit
```